# PHP avoid redirect

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

I'm wondering if there's any possibility of avoid redirect with my problem below.

**index.php**

```
$select = new select();

if(!isset($_COOKIE['country']) || !isset($_COOKIE['language'])){
   $select->firstTime();
   $content = $select->clients(); // this will get clients according to the cookies
}
```

**firstTime**

```
public function firstTime(){
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://freegeoip.net/xml/$ip");

    $locale    = $xml->CountryCode;

    $country_f   = "us"; // default
    $locale_f = "en_US"; // default

    /*
        ++ Select country from database according to the locale
        $country_f = $variable_database
    */

    setcookie('language', $locale_f, time() + (60*60*24*365), '/');
    setcookie('country', $country_f, time() + (60*60*24*365), '/');

    header('location: redirect.php');
    exit();
}
```

**redirect.php**

```
header('location: index.php'); exit(); // back to index.php
```

Well, the problem is this: when the user enters the page for the first time it has no cookies, so I check his ip and set the cookies. However, if the user does not refresh the page he will see the page content in the default language/country (English/United States), so I make this redirect to force the content to show according to user location.

The code `$content = $select->clients(); // this will get clients according to the cookies`, will select the clients according to his cookies. If I remove the `redirect` code the clients will be selected as default English/United States and shouldn't because the cookies were already stored with the function firstTime().

The function `$select->clients()` is read **AFTER** `$select->firstTime()`, so why doesn't detect the cookies?

**clients**

```
list($id_country, $id_language) = $this->get_country_language();
/*
  ... SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id_country = $id_country
*/
```

**get_country_language**

```
public function get_country_language(){
    $id_country = 2; // United States
    $id_language = 1; // English
    
    if(isset($_COOKIE['country'])){
        $id_country = $this->get_country_from_code($_COOKIE['country']);
    }
    if(isset($_COOKIE['language'])){
        $id_language = $load->get_language_from_code($_COOKIE['language']);
    }       
    
    return array($id_country, $id_language);
}
```

I've tried to be the most explicit I could. I'm just asking if there's any possibility of doing this without redirect? Because google says to avoid redirects..and when I analyse my page with google pagespeed it also says that.

> Your page has 2 redirects. Redirects introduce additional delays
> before the page can be loaded.
> mywebsite.com/
>
> mywebsite.com/redirect.php
>
> mywebsite.com/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setcookie sets the cookie information on the users browser, however current cookie information is only loaded at the start of the script.

A redirect/refresh is really the only way around this I believe.

Answer (score 0):

instead of redirect and exit() why dont you return the array($locale_f, $id_language);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this

```
public function get_country_language(){
    $id_country = 2; // United States
    $id_language = 1; // English
    $ids = array();

    if(isset($_COOKIE['country']) && isset($_COOKIE['language'])){
        $id_country = $this->get_country_from_code($_COOKIE['country']);
        $id_language = $load->get_language_from_code($_COOKIE['language']);
        $ids = array($id_country, $id_language);
    }       
    else{
        $ids = $this->firstTime();
    }
    return $ids;
    }

public function firstTime(){
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://freegeoip.net/xml/$ip");

    $locale    = $xml->CountryCode;

    $country_f   = "us"; // default
    $locale_f = "en_US"; // default

    /*
    ++ Select country from database according to the locale
    $country_f = $variable_database
    */

    setcookie('language', $locale_f, time() + (60*60*24*365), '/');
    setcookie('country', $country_f, time() + (60*60*24*365), '/');

    return array($country_f, $locale_f);
    }
```

... after this you can parse the content.

Comment: Humm, I understand your point of view and also your code. I'll give a try.

Comment: Well it didn't work, plus, the page takes more time to load the content (because it call firstTime() twice), which takes the page like 6 seconds to read.

With redirect takes 2 seconds.

Comment: okey, but why twice, did you call the firstTime() function in an other way?
i'll rewrite the code and test it again.